# Understand the Garbage collector logs flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, memory

Here is the output of my logging of my flutter app :

```
Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 25188(844KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 2% free, 301MB/309MB, paused 348us total 317.699ms
```

I would like to understand :

- What does "LOS" mean ?
- What is the "2% free" ? (The space that the garbage collector managed to free ? or the remaining RAM available ?)
- What represents the 301MB and the 309MB ?

As i am using the flutter DevTools to look for memory, i am seeing very different numbers :

’[image: here]

I have added the "Android" tag because i am running the app on Android 10 and i believe the answer would be the same for IOS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This log does not seem to come from Flutter but Android. I found this article which seems to explain the log line in more details: https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-android-gc-logs

Comment: Thank you, it actually answers my question !

Comment: Great, I have made an answer you can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This log messages are not coming from Flutter but Android itself. Based on the log format in your example I guess it is logging from ART (Android RunTime) and where the log format is described in details here the documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat?hl=lt#ARTLogMessages

So to answer your questions:

> What does "LOS" mean ?

Large Object Space

> What is the "2% free" ? (The space that the garbage collector managed to free ? or the remaining RAM available ?). What represents the 301MB and the 309MB ?

From the linked documentation:

> **Heap stats**
>
> Percentage free and (number of live objects)/(total heap size).

So your current heap takes 309 MB memory, contains objects which takes 301 MB inside it. Which means 2% of the heap is free to be used.